# Bootstrap columns not appearing on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I developed a `grid` with 3 columns. My problem is that the columns shrink too much and do not present the content correctly when they are adjusted in smaller sizes.

Is there a way to implement a break-point, so that when the screen measurement of approximately `1000px` arrives, pass all the content to a single column?

The other problem arises when I reach the mobile size, the last two columns (highlighted in the image) disappear. These should appear under the first column

How can I solve my problem and what did I do wrong?

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/n0ghuCLBK0)

**Code**

```html
<div class="container-fluid"
    style="overflow-x:hidden;padding-left:0;display:flex; height: 98vh; margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 customcol">
        <div class="card card1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">1asdas</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
            <div class="card card2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">2aasasddsd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">3asd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
            <div class="card card2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">4asdasd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">5asda</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
            <div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">6asda</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">7asd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">8asdasd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">9asdsad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 customcol">
        <div class="card card1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">10asd</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">11asdas</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 customcol">
        <div class="card cardall">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">12asd</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are using `col` without `row`.

When ever you need to use column there must be some row as its parent its define in official doc of [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)

```css
.card{
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;

}

.card-body{
    padding:4px;
}

.card1{
height: calc(50% - 16px)
}

.divh{
height: calc(16.7% - 16px);
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.card2{
width: calc(50% - 16px);
margin-top:0px;
height:100%;
}

.card4{
width: calc(25% - 16px);
margin-top:0px;
height:100%;
}

.cardall{
  height: calc(100% - 16px)

}

.customcol{
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:0; height: 98vh;">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 customcol">
<div class="card card1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">1asdas</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
  <div class="card card2" >
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">2aasasddsd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card2">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">3asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
  <div class="card card2">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">4asdasd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card2">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">5asda</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
  <div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">6asda</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">7asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">8asdasd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">9asdsad</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 customcol">
<div class="card card1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">10asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">11asdas</p>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 customcol">
  <div class="card cardall">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">12asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! The only problem is that the column named 12asd should be aligned horizontally, thus making 3 columns. Right now that column is below the first column

Comment: Updated my ans...please check i just put that in next col, and remember in one row there should no more then 12 cols. That's how bootstrap grid works, if you need more then create another row and then col.. @S3ckStros

Comment: Now the column has moved below column 2. I intend on a line, to have the 3 columns and occupying the page in full (in the row I added width: 100%). The problem continues, I can't have the 3 columns in the same row

Comment: @S3ckStros Can you explain a little bit please, just name the col you want to show in row with tier sequence please as i didnt get your point

Comment: Click on my demo link. In the top line (1st) remove this overflow-x: hidden; You will see 3 columns but using the overflox x. I intend to obtain these 3 columns, in the same row and adjusted the page, without using overflow. This 3rd column only appears visible if using the overflow I don't understand why :(

Comment: @S3ckStros If i remove overflow-x i got 3 col with 12 in last col, so this how you need ?

Comment: @S3ckStros Updated my ans.. i also add another solution in a while with using pure bootstrap classes to achieve this structure, Currently i corrected existing one in above solution...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card{
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;

}

.card-body{
    padding:4px;
}

.card1{
height: calc(50% - 16px)
}

.divh{
height: calc(16.7% - 16px);
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.card2{
width: calc(50% - 16px);
margin-top:0px;
height:100%;
}

.card4{
width: calc(25% - 16px);
margin-top:0px;
height:100%;
}

.cardall{
  height: calc(100% - 16px)

}

.customcol{
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:0; height: 98vh;">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 customcol">
<div class="card card1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">1asdas</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
  <div class="card card2" >
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">2aasasddsd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card2">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">3asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
  <div class="card card2">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">4asdasd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card2">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">5asda</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divh" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex">
  <div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">6asda</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">7asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">8asdasd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card4" style="height:100%">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">9asdsad</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 customcol">
<div class="card card1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">10asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">11asdas</p>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 customcol">
  <div class="card cardall">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">12asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```